# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list when sending email

Tags: python

I am getting this error when trying to send an email with user_id in a Receiver. Please someone advise how to get around it. Sample of my code:

```
if #something == True:
    user_id = q["user"]
    print user_id ####produces [['e11111'], ['e11234']]

    Sender = "Sender@sender.com"
    Receiver = (user_id[0:6] + '@co.com', 'john.smith@co.com')
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = "Subject"
    msg['From'] = Sender
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(Receiver)
    html = "text here"

    part = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(part)
```

This works fine with

```
Receiver = ('Joshua@co.com', 'john.smith@co.com')
```

Or if the print user_id produces only one result - e11111.
What I need is to send that email to e11111@co.com, e11234@co.com and john.smith@co.com

Comment: The error is clear. If you have a nested list for `user_id` then your indexing also produces a list that you then try to concatenate with a string. `list + str` is not possible.

Comment: If `user_id = [['e11111'], ['e11234']]`, then `user_id[0:6]` gives `[['e11111'], ['e11234']]`. What do you *expect* it to give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `user_id` is a list of lists of the form of `[['e11111'], ['e11234']]`, you can do:

```
 Receiver = tuple([i[0][0:6] + '@co.com' for i in user_id] + ['john.smith@co.com'])
```

This will extract the string from the 1-length lists inside `user_id` and append the `'@co.com'` string to them. john smith is concatenated to the resulting list and the final list is transformed into a tuple (I guess Receiver should be a tuple, if it is fine with a list you can omit the `tuple()`)

**EDIT after comment**

With `i[0][0:6]` only the first 6 characters of the strings are used.

Comment: This worked! One thing, sometimes user_id has extra characters like e11111@usa.net. I used to trim @usa.net with user_id[0:6]. How can i do the same in this situation

Answer (score 0):

As said, `user_id` here is a list of lists, not list of strings. So you can try

```
Receiver = (user_id[0][0] + '@sender', 'john.smith@co.com')
```

Note: `user_id[0] = ['e11111']` is still a list.

Comment: This only sends email to one of the user_id's in [['e11111'], ['e11234']]